# URL Alias in SharePoint Online for Login

Tags: url, login

We want to use the auto-logon capabilities for SharePoint Online as represented in this URL;

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&whr=mycompany.com&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.sharepoint.com
```

Is there a way to setup some alias like;

```
https://myalias.sharepoint.com
```

to point to the more complex URL?